# How to retrieve a columns values using LINQ in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

Suppose I have a database called **NorthWind**. It has a table named **Products** which has following columns.

- Product_Id
- Product_Name
- Price

I want to write an LINQ query to retrieve all the Product_Names from the database. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `Select(p=>Product_Name)`

Comment: Are you trying with entity framework?

Comment: Yes Shanish. I am trying with Entity framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a Domain Model for your table,

Then you can access your product table and get like this,

```
ProductDBContext.Products.Select(p => Product_Name);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am very new to LINQ. I have added the Domain model for my tables. Could you please elaborate a bit on ProductDBContext, which you have used in your answer.

Comment: ProductDBContext Is the object of the domainmodel you created!

Comment: I am using entity framework using ADO.Net entity data model in C# 4.0. I am not able to create the object of the domain model. I am not getting it in the intellicense itself.

Comment: That is whatam also refering to! you should be able to create!

Comment: After creating the model, Do i need to add the reference or something to my forms application?

Comment: Yes you should refer by adding it to your project!

Comment: It is already part of my project. I created it by using Add new item object to my project. Still i am not able to create an object of the model.

Answer (score 0):

```
dbContext.Products.Select(p => Product_Name)
```

Something like the above